# Using URLrewrite on static subdirectories

Tags: php, iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect random subdirectories to a handler script I made using IIS's URLrewrite. This rule I wrote works well for redirecting subdirectories to my handler script, but there are some real subdirectories (aka /wp-admin and /contact) that get redirected to my handler as well:

```
<rule name="Rewrite to article.aspx">
  <match url="^states/([a-z _]+)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="states.php?state={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

How can I ensire that /wp-admin and /contact actually go to the real subdirectories, but everything else goes to my cistom handler using URLrewrite?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a *condition* to a rule--use the URL Rewrite Module in IIS Manager to help construct those.  Alternatively, add a prior rule and stop processing if true.  Here are some rules you can cut/paste directly into your web.config:

```
<rule name="pass wp-admin through" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^wp-admin/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" />
</rule>
<rule name="pass contact through" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^contact/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" />
</rule>
<!-- insert your other rules here-->
```